# Vim-latex suite background compilation

Tags: vim-latex

I can't seem to find this option in the documentation. Is there a way to not freeze vim while the compilation is going on? What I would like is to say type "\ll" and have vim-latex run the compilation in the background, and provided there are errors, bring up quickfix.

Is that possible? Easy?

Comment: I don't use vim-latex but another plugin. Presumably somewhere in the vim-latex configuration you have a line like `let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode $*'`. If so simply putting this into background should be enough: `let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode $* &'`

Comment: @Andrew actually this won't background the compilation unfortunately....

Answer (score 1):

Vim is known to be bad at asynchronism, but plugins exist such as [AsyncCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431) allowing you to run commands in the background and see the output in a split once the command finished. AsyncCommand comes with an AsyncMake command, which can be used to `make` asynchronously. Therefore, in my vimrc I use :

```
noremap <leader>mm :AsyncMake<cr>
```

to map `<leader>mm` to asynchronous make, and

```
:autocmd BufEnter *.tex let &makeprg="latexmk -e '$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode/' -pdf ".expand("<amatch>")
```

to set the `make` program to latexmk when I open tex files.

Comment: This is great, but doesn't completely address the question. Can someone with experience with vim-latex suite chime in on where the edits need to be made to incorporate this? I would have preferred a solution that doesn't  add yet another plugin to the mix if one is available.

Comment: In particular, there is a way to background the command by adding & to the end of the rule, I just don't know where to add it so that \ll backgrounds the compilation

Comment: The background is obtained via `AsyncMake`, which itself runs the make command in the background. The solution I propose would also compile any project with regular make in the backgound. I would rather use one global tool to background everything, rather than let every plugin cook its onwn solution, but I admit this is my own choice.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncCommand requires vim to be compiled with clientserver, which may or may not require a new compilation, and definitely will for those of us running Cygwin (after installing Cygwin/X).

An alternative that worked right away for me was the [dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin, which provides the `Start!` command.  I have the following in my vimrc:

```
map <leader>lr :w<CR>:Start! latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape \%O \%S" % && latexmk -c %<CR>
```

This allows me to skip manually writing the file before compilation, and also cleans up after compilation (the `latexmk -c` command).  A simpler variant would be

```
map <leader>lr :Start! latexmk -pdf % <CR>
```